# c++:templates by value of a type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class A, which i want to be templated based on boolean value. If true do certain things, if false do something else.

Now class B is the one which needs class A as a member.  In class B i need something like:

```
class B {
#ifdef PRODUCT1
static A<true> proxy_;
#else
static A<false> proxy_;
#endif
}
```

I am stuck at various points, my sample code is below, its giving lots of errors i am unable to understand. Could anyone please help.

templ.h

```
 #define PRODUCT1

    template<bool T>
    class A {
    public:
    void init(){
    if(T) {
       valid_ = 1;
    } else {
       valid_ = 0;
    }
    }
    int valid_;
    };

    class B {
    public:
    template<bool T>
    static A<T> proxy_;
    };
```

templ.cpp

```
#include "templ.h"
#ifdef PRODUCT1
template<> A<bool> B::proxy_<true>;
#else
template<> A<bool> B::proxy_<false>;
#endif


main(){

B::proxy_.init();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
template<bool> struct A;

// explicit specializations for true and false
template<> struct A<true>
{ /* whatever */ };
template<> struct A<false>
{ /* whatever */ };

template<bool BParam> struct B
{
  static A<BParam> ainstance;
};

// definition of the static data member
template<bool BParam>
A<BParam> B<BParam>::ainstance;
```

The definition of the `static` instance can be in the header, that's OK for templates. Include this file in whatever cpp file you're using `B` in.

---

If you want to go the preprocessor route instead of making `B` a class template, do this:

```
struct B
{
#ifdef A_TRUE
  static A<true> ainstance;
#else
  static A<false> ainstance;
#endif
};

#ifdef A_TRUE
A<true> B::ainstance;
#else
A<false> B::ainstance;
#endif
```

Comment: 1] I want to avoid making class B a template. Can i do that? Sorry i did not mention this earlier. 2] Can i club template specializations into one class?

Comment: @Pkp Updated, but making `B` a class template is really the better solution.

Comment: Thanks to both your answers. I did not know we can specialize by value (we are doing by true or false here), I thought we can write template specialization for a particular type say char. Could you point me to any docs that talk about this.

Comment: @Pkp Search for "non-type template parameters". When the template parameter is a *type* (`template<typename T> ...`), you can specialize it for a given type, say `char`. Here you have a *non-type template parameter* (`template<bool B>`), so you're allowed to provide specializations for values that that parameter can hold.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for both the answers: I optimized it further and got what i was looking for. Here is it for all the folks out there.

templ.h

```
template<bool T>
class A {
public:
void init(){
if(T)
   valid_ = 1;
else
   valid_ = 0;
}
int valid_;
};

class B {
public:
#ifdef PRODUCT1
static A<true> proxy_;
#else
static A<false> proxy_;
#endif
};
```

templ.cpp

```
#include "templ.h"

A<true> B::proxy_;

main(){

B::proxy_.init();

}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `init()` function at all. Initialize `valid_` in `A`'s constructor. You should also add `#ifdef - #else` around the definition for the `proxy_`, or do what [MooingDuck suggested](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/753692fe7f497b05)